# How to hash a token of 1000 characters or more using password_hash function in php?

Tags: php

I have a token of around 1400 characters, and I want to hash it using the password_hash function but using the PASSWORD_DEFAULT algorithm will only generate the hash using only first 72 characters. I have explored PASSWORD_ARGON2I algorithm, but I am not sure if it is considering the full token length of 1400 characters.

I have tested the following:

```
php -r echo password_hash(<$embedtokenhere>, PASSWORD_ARGON2I) . "\n";
```

This will give me the result as

```
$argon2i$v=19$m=1024,t=2,p=2$cUdEZjFHN2lHYzUwR2hqeg$aRzXaa1RAArMl+cwuczG6rng2omZjqJnaImnh4ZvxeM
```

Is it hashing considering all the characters or does the PASSWORD_ARGON2I has a limit length for the input string to be hashed?

Comment: Why are you trying to hash a token with a password function? You need to describe your use case in more detail, because you should probably be using `hash_hmac()`.

Comment: I need this to insert into one of the server tables, which is using the password_verify() function and the token that will be verified is stored in the db table with the hash string using password_php function. So when the user logs in he will use the token that is stored with the hashed string of password_hash() function. Does hash string generated using the hash_hmac() can be verified with the password_verify() function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the documentation of `password_hash`, you will see this:

> **CAUTION** Using the PASSWORD_BCRYPT as the algorithm, will result in the password parameter being truncated to a maximum length of 72 characters.

This only applies for PASSWORD_BCRYPT, which is the default hashing algo for `password_hash`. If you use `PASSWORD_ARGON2I`, this limitation doesn't exists.

But you should keep in mind, that `PASSWORD_ARGON2I` only exists in PHP7.2 and newer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer I would provide is don't hash it using password_hash. 1400 characters *should* have enough entropy that a simple `sha256` / `sha3` would suffice. The reason is that `password_hash` is designed for low entropy inputs (< 128 bits of entropy), as the computation time offsets the low entropy and makes it harder to attack. But for high entropy inputs, that computation time is wasted effort.

Whether or not a salt is necessary depends on your use-case. My instinct is that it isn't (given how much entropy is in a 1400 token anyway), but it depends specifically on how the token is generated, and what it's used for.

If you need a salt, simply use `hash_hmac()` to hash the token with the salt. Otherwise use `hash()`.

Comment: I am using a backend that is storing the token, and I need to use this token to login to the server once I insert the token into the token table. I want to store the token hashed with the password_hash() function because the passwords will be verified with the help of the password_verify() function in the backend.

Comment: In the same way if the token is stored with the password_hash() function then the token will be verified or else it won't. I tried the hash() function with the sha512 algorithm, but the token won't be verified because it will be checked in the backend with the password_verify() function, so is there any other way, other than ARGON2I.

Comment: I am using one of the systems in the backend that uses the methodology to hash the token using password_hash() before inserting into the db table (it is designed that way), so it can be only verified with the password_verfiy().

Answer (score 0):

hash the token, hex encode the hash, password_hash the hex.

```
php -r echo password_hash(hash('sha256',$embedtokenhere), PASSWORD_ARGON2I) . "\n";
```